# Optgroup filtering with special characters

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var branches = $('#branch_name').html();
var filtrate = optgroup[label="Abe's Milk"]
var options = $(branches).filter(filtrate).html();
```

I get this:

```
throw new Error ( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

but if I put:

```
var filtrate = optgroup[label="Abes Milk"]
```

No error.

I tried automatically escaping the single quote in Abe's with a regular expression, but this failed as well because no optgroup matched Abe\'s Milk.

Please Help. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you have found a bug in jQuery. See if you can reproduce it with the latest version. If you can't: upgrade. If you can: File a bug report. The jQuery source code is on GitHub, consider forking it, fixing the bug and making a pull request.

Comment: Yes it would seem that way Quentin. Looks like I'll need to do some input restrictions in my text input to get around this for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried automatically escaping the single quote in Abe's with a
>   regular expression, but this failed as well because no optgroup
>   matched Abe\'s Milk.

Try:

```
optgroup[label="Abe\'s Milk"]
```